# How to maintain a unique key generated in JPA Entity via ValueGenerator across multiple instances of a springmvc app during load balancing

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, oracle11g, spring-data-jpa, multiple-instances

I have a jpa Entity which already have a id generated as uuid and one more unique human readable id was required. so I generated a ref_key with `ValueGenerator`.

```
@Id@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
@Type(type = "uuid-char")@Column(name="ID")
private UUID id;

@GeneratorType(type = UniqueIdGenerator.class, when = GenerationTime.INSERT)
@Column(name = "REF_KEY", updatable = false, insertable = true, unique = true, nullable = false)
private String refKey;
```

For generating this unique ref_key, I used timestamp and a simple counter. The code is below

```
public class UniqueIdGenerator implements ValueGenerator {

    private static volatile String lastTimestamp = "";
    private static volatile int counter = 1;
    private String valuePrefix = "UNI_";

    @Override
    public String generateValue(Session session, Object owner) {
        return generateUniqueId(valuePrefix);
    }

    private static synchronized String generateUniqueId(String prefix) {
        String id;
        Date dNow = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd_HHmmss");
        String datetimeId = ft.format(dNow);
        if (lastTimestamp.equalsIgnoreCase(datetimeId)) {
            id = prefix + datetimeId + "_" + counter;
            counter++;
        } else {
            id = prefix + datetimeId;
            counter = 1;
        }
        lastTimestamp = datetimeId;
        return id;
    }
}
```

All this working fine with one instance. But multiple instances are getting deployed for this application for load balancing, so Its very high probability that same id would be generated and inserted in DB at very same moment. How can I avoid getting duplicates in DB ? What could be a better approach ?

DB used Oracle 11g.

I tried few different things before coming to this approach like using sequence from DB end but it didn't worked out and whole model/entity part is getting packaged separately, I was not able to hit DB from This portion. What else  can be done to have a unique counter value generated and inserted in DB as per instances. Please help.

Comment: 'I was not able to hit DB from This portion' - See [this article](https://thorben-janssen.com/custom-sequence-based-idgenerator/) on how to 'hit DB'

Comment: Thanks crizzis, I implemented whole thing from this article as well, same implementation was not working for me. This sequence generator works with @Id annotation. And in my case Id was already available. so GenericGenrator didn't worked.

Comment: Fair enough, but `generateValue` gives you access to the `Session` meaning that you can execute literally any query you like. Just use `session.createSQLQuery("SELECT mySequence.NEXTVAL FROM dual")`

Comment: tried that as well crizzis but it was not working, I was getting SQL exception saying invalid identifiers as far as i remember, while trying to get ResultList or UniqueResult etc.. tried createQuery, createSQLQuery, createNativeQuery... but nothing worked.

Comment: Well, if you're getting an 'invalid identifier', that means you're trying to access a DB object that does not exist. BUT, it also means you just managed to access the DB. You just need to issue a valid query.

Comment: okay, thanks crizzis, may be i will retry that... but is there any way to maintain uniqueness of this key as per current implementation in case multiple instances deployed and running ?

Comment: Yes. The db providing sequence numbers guarantees uniqueness. There needs to be a single source for the numbers all of the instances use to synchronize and coordinate, and the DB is the most obvious choice. That's precisely why this is the recommended approach. After all, that's how you guarantee uniqueness for all the other ids in your application, isn't it?